# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.close

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running two map-reduce pairs. The output of first map-reduce is being used as the input for the next map-reduce. In order to do that I have given the job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class). While running the following Driver class:

```html
package org;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VarLongWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;

public class Driver1 extends Configured implements Tool
{
 
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
   
  if(args.length !=3) {
  System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemperatureDriver <input path> <outputpath>");
  System.exit(-1);
  }
  //ConfFactory WorkFlow=new ConfFactory(new Path("/input.txt"),new Path("/output.txt"),TextInputFormat.class,VarLongWritable.class,Text.class,VarLongWritable.class,VectorWritable.class,SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
  Job job = new Job();
  Job job1=new Job();
  job.setJarByClass(Driver1.class);
  job.setJobName("Max Temperature");
 
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));
   
  job.setMapperClass(UserVectorMapper.class);
  job.setReducerClass(UserVectorReducer.class);
   
  job.setOutputKeyClass(VarLongWritable.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(VectorWritable.class);
  job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
  
  job1.setJarByClass(Driver1.class);
  //job.setJobName("Max Temperature");
  job1.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
 
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path("output/part-r-00000"));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1,new Path(args[2]));
   
  job1.setMapperClass(ItemToItemPrefMapper.class);
  //job1.setReducerClass(UserVectorReducer.class);
   
  job1.setOutputKeyClass(VectorWritable.class);
  job1.setOutputValueClass(VectorWritable.class);
  job1.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) && job1.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
  boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
  return success ? 0 : 1;
  
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Driver1 driver = new Driver1();
  int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(driver, args);
  System.exit(exitCode);
  }
  }
```

I am getting the following runtime log.

```html
15/02/24 20:00:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/02/24 20:00:49 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/02/24 20:00:49 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/02/24 20:00:49 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1723586736_0001
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1723586736_0001_m_000000_0
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1185f32
15/02/24 20:00:49 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/smaiti/workspace/recommendationsy/data.txt:0+1979173
15/02/24 20:00:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
15/02/24 20:00:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
15/02/24 20:00:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
15/02/24 20:00:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/24 20:00:50 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1723586736_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1723586736_0001_m_000000_0' done.
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1723586736_0001_m_000000_0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@9cce9
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 2074779 bytes
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1723586736_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1723586736_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1723586736_0001_r_000000_0' to output
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1723586736_0001_r_000000_0' done.
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local1723586736_0001
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 20
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=1012481
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=1979173
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=6033479
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=5264031
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=943
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=2074783
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=100000
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=943
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=200000
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=1874777
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=415760384
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=118
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=100000
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=100000
15/02/24 20:00:51 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/02/24 20:00:51 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local735350013_0002
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local735350013_0002_m_000000_0
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1a970
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/smaiti/workspace/recommendationsy/output/part-r-00000:0+1004621
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.MapTask: Ignoring exception during close for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader@9cc591
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.close(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:101)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:496)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1776)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:778)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/24 20:00:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
15/02/24 20:00:51 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local735350013_0002
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable
 at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3208)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:795)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:964)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:673)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/02/24 20:00:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/24 20:00:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local735350013_0002
15/02/24 20:00:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

The first exception that I am getting is this:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.close(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:101)

Please help.

Comment: This might be a problem with your input file. Did you try running only with the first few lines of your input file?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have the same problem.
In your case, I see another MR output as input path. Does your code ingnore _SUCCESS files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly because Hadoop is confused while Serializing the data.

Make sure to

1. You should set Input and output file format class to both the reducers.
2. Check that Inputformat of second class is OutputFormat of first class.
3. It might be possible that intermediate file format is different from what the reducer is expecting to read.
4. Maintain consistent FileFormats across your program.